# difference between filtered token and restricted token

Tags: security, winapi, operating-system

Is there a difference between Restricted Token and Filtered Token.
From what I can see, they both seem synonymous, but the Windows Internals book has confused me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft appear to use "restricted token" and "filtered token" interchangeably at least some of the time, e.g., [in the documentation for TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> TokenHasRestrictions
>
> The buffer receives a DWORD value that is nonzero if the token has ever been filtered.

However, "filtered token" is most often used in the specific context of UAC, to describe the restricted token generated by UAC when an administrator logs on.  For a restricted token generated in any other way, it is probably safer to stick to "restricted".